# JavaMail set domain in property

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to overwrite the domain which an email will come from via a property?

Currently I'm using `setFrom(InternetAddress)` on [javax.mail.Message](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setFrom(javax.mail.Address)) and then executing via :

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ian@x.co.uk"));
```

However I need x.co.uk to be configurable per environment. I was hoping I could do this automatically via a property on the JNDI?

1. Is there a mail.x property for setting the domain?
2. Is it possible to declare arbitrary properties on a JNDI Resource?

Comment: I tried mail.from but it didnt work, the original domain was still suffixed

Comment: Yes you can sorry, user error

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override where you come from with the API. It's for security reason. Technically you can. But you shouldn't do it.

Comment: You can set the From address to any string you want.  The issue is, will your mail server let you send a message with an arbitrary From address?  Generally they won't, but it really depends on the configuration of your mail server.  If you want it to be "configurable per environment" where each environment has a different mail server for a different domain, you can (and should) set the From address to some address in that domain.

Comment: I don't know the term environment means.. is it a server?

Comment: I was quoting the submitter.  What did he mean when he said "environment"?  It could be different servers, different companies, whatever.